# Transaction Groups - assimilating transactions started and committed in other methods

Tags: revit-api

I was wondering if there was a way to group and assimilate various transactions that are started and committed in other methods. And then for example in my pseudocode:

```cs
public class Main: IExternalCommand
{
 public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, elementSet elements)
   {
     TransactionGroup transactiongroup = new TransactionGroup(document,"Combined Transactions");
     transactiongroup.Start()
     
     Parameterpass_method(commandData);
     
     Sketch_method(commandData);
     
     transcationgroup.Assimilate();
     transactiongroup.Commit();

     return Result.Succeeded;

   }
  private void Parameterpass_method(ExternalCommandData commandData)
  {
    Document document = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

    Transaction trans = new Transaction(document,"parameter pass");
    trans.Start();
    // Code for this method ie. whatever I want and works
    trans.Commit();
  }

   private void Sketch_method(ExternalCommandData commandData)
  {
    Document document = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

    Transaction trans = new Transaction(document,"parameter pass");
    trans.Start();
    // Code for this method ie. whatever I want and works
    trans.Commit();
  }

}
```

By trying this method, I was not getting any errors, however I was not getting any output to my Revit family. I was wondering if this is because my approach is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the Revit API documentation on [TransactionGroup.Assimilate](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/158471e4-5554-16ed-f9bf-f7499b86309c.htm) and [TransactionGroup.Commit](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/11878443-43f2-63fb-a95d-baa1eeab776d.htm) and study the sample code provided with each. It clearly shows that you call either `Assimilate` or `Commit`, not both, and that they have different effects.

Comment: Ok thank you. But would I be able to implement my methodology of using various methods to add different transactions to my Plugin.

Comment: @JeevanGopinath, yes, that should work without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is that you are calling both `transcationgroup.Assimilate()` and `transactiongroup.Commit()`. If you only call one of those methods things should work just fine, even if you transactions are spread across multiple classes and methods, but then rolled up into one `TransactionGroup`.

Per the [API Docs](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/f1113d30-4c36-7844-1537-aad7f095cea0.htm):

> There are two ways of committing a group - `Commit` and `Assimilate`. By committing, all transactions committed inside a group stay as they are, while by assimilating, all inner transactions will be merged into a single transaction.

I will often use a TransactionGroup at the very top level of a command and have transactions peppered throughout as needed. This allows me to present the user with one transaction and more importantly ***one undo function***.

Do note that every transaction slows down your command as it will require some amount of overhead from refreshing and regenerating geometry, so you want to keep those to a minimum -- usually just where Revit needs those changes committed to the document before you can perform your next action.

```cs
public Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, elementSet elements)
{
     TransactionGroup transactiongroup = new TransactionGroup(document,"Combined Transactions");
     transactiongroup.Start()

     Parameterpass_method(commandData);

     Sketch_method(commandData);

     // all transactions rolled into one undo
     transcationgroup.Assimilate(); 
     
     // each transaction shows in undo
     // transactiongroup.Commit(); 

     return Result.Succeeded;

}
```